# Switching between repos

Tags: git, bitbucket

For almost 3 years, we have been developing on a git repo that is hosted on `ssh://me@foo.com:40000/myproject.git` . Now I have to transfer the files to my client git repo which is `ssh://git@bitbucket.bar.com:7999/w3/myproject.git`.

Then developers need to start working transferred repo which is the bitbucket one.

So i have two questions, what is the best way to transfer the code between repos?

Then what is the best way for developers to start working on the new repo? is it possible just to change the remote-url ? The project is huge and I would love to avoid developers to spend a full day on building the project, configuring etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to edit the remote URL. It depends on your git-client, but at the layer of bare GUI-less git, just look at `.git/config` file and you will find all definitions of remotes there.

```
[core]
    bare = false
    (.....)
[user]
    name = you
    email = your@email.com
[remote "origin"]                                #<---- here ya go '1
    url = ssh://me@foo.com:40000/myproject.git   #<--- here ya go '2
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

So, you can change it, zip the `.git`, give it to the other dev, and he's ready to go. Yuck. Don't do it that way unless you're at point blank.

That's because there's not much sense in doing that all manually. Git can easily handle multiple remotes, and you've got `push` which can initialize the new remote repo for you, and `clone` which can set up developers to work.. Probably it will be even more convenient for you to (at least temporarily) keep both remotes configured.

Assuming you already have traditional `origin` just add the new one under a new name:

```
git remote add newrepo ssh://git@bitbucket.bar.com:7999/w3/myproject.git
```

after that .. just push

```
git push newrepo master
```

or

```
git push --all
git push --tags
... etc
```

After that, the new-repo will contain "everything" (=depends on what you've jsut pushed) from the source one, and new developers can simply `clone/pull` from that new one, ignoring the old one.

Since you are doing a normal push, the new-repo will also get a **full history**. If you don't want that, you will need to trim it first (squash, etc).

Comment: What if I can't do `git remote add newrepo` because it already exists and have some old code in it.

Comment: @DarthVader: ..your new repository contains some old code? A bit peculiar, isn't it? Anyways, assuming you want to drop that old code and replace it with the newest - clean up the new repo first: delete all branches except `master` (because you probably won't be able to delete `master` beucase probably it's the default branch on server's bare repo), and then force-push an orphaned empty commit to the `master` branch. After that your new-repo will be totally empty and ready to receive contents pushed from your actual source repo.

Answer (score 1):

`$ git remote add <new_origin_name> <new_origin_url>`

is the command. Here, new_origin_name can be some name other than what you have given to the old remote repo. Then force push to the new repo:

```
$ git push --force <new_origin_name>
```

If --force is too strong, you can use --force-with-lease. Your other developers need to do exactly the same (except using the --force option of course!).

And for Bitbucket (on Windows/Mac), it may not be a bad idea for everyone to use the Atlassian software [sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), which helps people do all this on a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Since usually git clones the whole repository you really don't need to do much besides cloning.
The developers just need to either change URL of their 'origin' or clone the new URL under a different name and remember to push there.
Personally I would delete remote origin and then add remote origin.

Comment: well thanks for that. and what would be the syntax ? I can try that out right now.